# Alps Potentiometer identification

Tags: identification

I have a native instruments Kontrol Z2 JD mixer, the low, mid, treble and filter pots all require replacing (they all have the came part number on them) 103B 636C. I am fairly certain they are from the Rk11K series. 103B I'm assuming is the taper and resistance, but what is the 636C part? I am not able to find this specific part anywhere.

I have another native instruments product that has the same 103B pots, but with a 352C prefix that do the same functions, Low, Mid, Treble and filter.

Would these be interchangeable? If not, how can I identify the exact specs of the 636C?

Comment: When you buy a pot from the manufacturer you get to choose such things as 'D' shaft vs. spline or round and to specify the length of the shaft. So there can be a lot of extra information to be conveyed.

Answer (score 1):

In general, they should be interchangeable.

The 103B is the resistance and taper, namely 10x10^3Ω and "B" taper.  Careful though, "B" can mean different things for different manufacturers.

The rest of the digits are usually a mix-match of production date, facility, series, etc.  There is no discernable rhyme or reason across vendors.

In general, if you can match the knob style, mounting style, resistance, taper, and the approximate power rating (size), the replacement should work.

I once replaced a 10k linear pot from a SWR bass amp. Despite it being standard-looking by all definitions, it was an unusual taper and metric size, which made finding a replacement challenging. Ended up having to pick a similar taper (not exact) but luckily the difference is minimal. Some manufacturers might have custom pots made for them, which further complicates replacement.  Also find a local instrument repair shop and ask them if they can get the pot - they might have "insider" access to OEM parts. Did that once for a PortaStudio fader.